# Python pandas automatically sorts columns

Tags: python, pandas

i create a csv file from a pandas dataframe with lots of columns for our ERP system. Most of the columns are empty or constant, but the importtool of the system expects a csv file with a specified column order.

When creating the dataframe, i have something like that:

```
importlist = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': 'TestA',
                            'C': some values,
                            'B': '0'})
```

When i print the list, the columns are ordered A, B, C.

Is there a way to prevent automatical ordering? I know i could sort the columns manually again, but i think, this would't be a very nice solution, because there are about 50 columns.

Comment: Do you really create a dataframe like this or read data source from text file or database?

Comment: I have to create a DataFrame like this. This is a bill of material for pcbs which are imported in our ERP system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, you can also use an `OrderedDict` which you pass a list of two element tuples where the first element of the tuple is the column name and the second element is a list of values.

```
pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([('A',['TestA', 'TestB']), 
                          ('C', ['Some Item', 'Other Item']),
                         ('B',[0, 1])]))

       A           C  B
0  TestA   Some Item  0
1  TestB  Other Item  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pass parameter `columns` with list of your columns of desired order, because default python `dict` is un-ondered:

```
importlist = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': 'TestA',
                        'C': some values,
                        'B': '0'}, columns = ['A','C','B'])
```

Sample:

```
importlist = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['TestA'],
                            'C':  [4],
                            'B': ['0']}, columns = ['A','C','B'])

print (importlist)
       A  C  B
0  TestA  4  0
```

Or use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for reading `csv` if possible.

In [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#alternate-constructors) are another methods for creating `DataFrames`, one of them is 
[`DataFrame.from_items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html):

```
a = ['TestA','TestB']
b = ['0', '7']
c = [4,7]

print (pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', a), ('C', c),('B', b)]))
       A  C  B
0  TestA  4  0
1  TestB  7  7
```